# Shopify - Video & Feature Media

Tags: shopify

For each of my product I will have 1 picture and 1 video.
Very basically I'm trying to show the picture in one part of my product-template and the video somewhere else.

My picture will always be the first media uploaded (therefore the "featured media") and the video always be second.

Therefore I want to update this code from "show the featured_media" to "show the video in the list of media" :

```
      {%- assign featured_media = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_media | default: product.featured_media -%}

      {% for media in product.media %}
      {% include 'media', media: media, featured_media: featured_media, height: height, enable_image_zoom: enable_image_zoom, image_zoom_size: product_image_zoom_size, image_scale: product_image_scale %}
      {%- endfor -%}

      <noscript>
        {% capture product_image_size %}{{ height }}x{% endcapture %}
        <img src="{{ featured_media | img_url: product_image_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" alt="{{ featured_media.alt }}" id="FeaturedMedia-{{ section.id }}" class="product-featured-media" style="max-width: {{ height }}px;">
      </noscript>
```

I have tried playing around with the featured_media assignement but can't figure how to simply extract the video (or the second media) and display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the idea for you to work with.

When you clicked on the image/video you have on the product admin page, you can set `alt text`.  This value can get called by `media.alt` when you loop through the set of `product.media`.  check the condition of the `media.alt` and display or hide stuff as you like.

```
{% for media in product.media %}
    {% if media.alt contains 'myVideo' %}
        do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another example, this one check for the media type `media.media_type` and display the content.

```
{% for media in product.media %}
  {% case media.media_type %}
    {% when 'image' %}
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="{{ media | img_url: '100x100'}}" alt="{{ media.alt }}">
       </div>
    {% when 'external_video' %}
      <div class="product-single__media">
        {{ media | external_video_tag }}
      </div>
    {% when 'video' %}
      <div class="product-single__video">
        {{ media | video_tag: controls: true }}
      </div>
    {% when 'model' %}
      <div class="product-single__media">
        {{ media | model_viewer_tag }}
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="product-single__media">
        {{ media | media_tag }}
      </div>
  {% endcase %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/product-media

Comment: Thanks Charles, that really helped me get to where I wanted.
Now I have a different issue though as the "controls:true" is mandatory to have the play button but implies that my video becomes downloadable...
If you happen to know how to impact this setting I would love some help. 
Regardless, thanks again for your help !

Comment: do you mean `controlsList="nodownload"` [https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html)

Comment: Yes absolutely. But I can't figure how to append the controlsList element to the video created.

Comment: Never mind Charles, I have found a way around using the Shopify video player instead. Thanks again for your help !